# Django-Ajax (Jquery) delete function problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm having some problem with my Django/Ajax delete-function. I have a list-template where every object has a deletebutton which makes an ajax post to href="/delete/{{ some.id }}".

View:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def Deleteobject(request, id):
    someobject = get_object_or_404(Mymodel, pk=id)
    response = {}
    if someobject.user == request.user:
        someobject.delete()
        response["status"] = "Delete"
    else:
        response["status"] = "Notdelete"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

Whats wrong here? The "delete" itself seems to work. But the window.confirm acts very strange where i sometimes need to click OK/Cancel multiple times. The Ajax-success response where I want to remove the deleted div from the list does not work at all.

Template:

```
  $("#contentdiv").on("click", ".deletebutton", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var val = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    if(val == true) {

      $.ajax({ 
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            //data: data,
            type: 'get',
            success: function(response) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(response);

                if (res['status'] == 'Delete') {
                  $( ".thelist" ).remove( "#listid" + $(this).attr("id") );
                  alert('successful!');
                }

                else if (res['status'] == 'Notdelete') {
                  delete res['status']   
                  alert('error!');  
                }
            }        
      }); 
    } 
  });
```

EDIT: Forgot a # on the remove function..
EDIT2: Changed from "post" to "get"..

URL:

```
    url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$','mymodels.views.Deleteobject'),
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the id to the post method,

here the id would come somthing like:

id = request.POST.get['id']
and then u can pass the id, u can pass it like this too:

```
$("#contentdiv").on("click", ".deletebutton", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var val = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
if(val == true) {

  $.ajax({ 
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        //data: data,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(response) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(response);

            if (res['status'] == 'Delete') {
              $( ".thelist" ).remove( "#listid" + $(this).attr("id") );
              alert('successful!');
            }

            else if (res['status'] == 'Notdelete') {
              delete res['status']   
              alert('error!');  
            }
        }        
  }); 
}
```

Edit: Forgot a # on the remove function..

Comment: Oops. Edited the wrong post. Sorry. But i don't understand exactly what you mean. Should i change from post to get? I don't think the problem is with the ID. Each div in the list has an id-attribute so can identify which div to remove. Each button has an id-attribute But even if i try only with the "alerts" and not the remove function i doesn't work.

Comment: yes you have to change the post to get, and if u still want to use post then u have to get the post data using request.POST.get['id'], for get method u can pass the id like u r doing right now

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll try with the 'get' then. I've added the URL in my original post.

Comment: Simply changing to "get" did not work. The deleting of the object do work in the view / backend (with both post or get) but somethings wrong in the frontend i can't get an alert message or remove the div. Seem like it doesn't read the response or something. The if-statement simply doesn't do what it should. I do get the {"status": "Delete"} as far as i can see.

Comment: are you sure that the success function triggered ? then , is the json response parsed correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

### frm.submit(function () {

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

                $("#response").html(data);
                setTimeout(function(){
                   window.location.reload(1);
                }, 3000);

                //add success function here
                // $("#SOME-DIV").html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                // alert("not working");
                $("#response").html("Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); ##
```

finally use this please:

```
 class symbolExist(View):
def get(self, request, name, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        symbol = symbol.lower()
        model = MODEL.objects.get(name=name)
        return HttpResponse("Sorry, \'"+str(name)+"\' is not available. Please Choose another one")
```

this is an ajax call that i used to check the name using ajax,

the ajax call i used is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#id_name" ).change(function(e) {
                    var el = $("#id_namel").val();
                    var url = '/isthe/nameExist/'
                    console.log(url.concat(el)  );
                    $.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
                        type: 'GET', //Method type
                        url: url.concat(el)  //Your form processing file url
                    }).done(function(data){
                            $('#nameExist').html(data);


                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```